# Display numbers, operator signs, and sum in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I am relatively new to Xcode. I am making a dice roller app in which six buttons representing six different dice (from d4 to d20) can be pressed, and the roll for the most recently tapped dice is displayed in one UILabel. There is also a Clear button that resets the label to 0. That part is complete.

What I am having trouble with is this: I want the amounts rolled to also show up in a second UILabel that displays each roll and the sum as the buttons are tapped, until the user taps the clear button. For example, say the user tapped the d4 and got a 3, the d8 and got a 5, and the d20 and got a 12-- I would want the second UILabel to be displaying "3=3", "3+5=8", and finally "3+5+12=20".

I know how to program the basic addition function if I was just outputting the sum itself, just not sure how to get the roll to simultaneously display in both labels along with the plus and equals signs in the second label. I don't need everything explicitly spelled out, just to be pointed in the right direction. I'm also new to stack overflow, so I apologize if I'm being too wordy or asking the wrong type of question. Thanks in advance!

*Edit* Below I have included a link to the image, as well as the text, of my code so far- very basic, as I am just learning Xcode and Swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Sum label and Roll label
    @IBOutlet weak var rollLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sumLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    //Dice/Clear buttons
    @IBAction func d20Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let d20Roll = arc4random_uniform(20) + 1
        rollLabel.text = "\(d20Roll)"   
    }

    @IBAction func d12Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let d12Roll = arc4random_uniform(12) + 1
        rollLabel.text = "\(d12Roll)"
    }

    @IBAction func d10Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let d10Roll = arc4random_uniform(10) + 1
        rollLabel.text = "\(d10Roll)"
    }

    @IBAction func d8Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let d8Roll = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1
        rollLabel.text = "\(d8Roll)"
    }

    @IBAction func d6Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let d6Roll = arc4random_uniform(6) + 1
        rollLabel.text = "\(d6Roll)"
    }

    @IBAction func d4Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let d4Roll = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1
        rollLabel.text = "\(d4Roll)"
    }
    @IBAction func clearButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        rollLabel.text = "0"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to provide your code so far?  Thank you!

Comment: You can have a single `@IBAction` hooked to **all** buttons, and some logic inside it to tell **who** is `sender`. It is a smarter and more scalable design in my opinion.

Comment: @Nicolas I was wondering if that was possible- in doing some research I had seen some people combining several buttons in one function, but I didn't know if I could do so since they were using different parameters to generate the random numbers.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You have two choices that I can think of rihgt now: Differentiate each button using the `tag: Int` property of `UIView` (set in the storyboard inspector), or have outlets (references) to each button and compare the value of `sender` to each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a history of values as well

```
var history: [Int] = []

var labelText = "" // your second label text

for number in history {
    labelText.append(String(number))
    if history.last == number {
        labelText.append("=")
    } else {
        labelText.append("+")
    }
}

labelText.append(String(history.reduce(0, +)))

sumLabel.text = labelText
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would want the second UILabel to be displaying "3=3", "3+5=8", and finally "3+5+12=20".

You definitely need an array that keeps track of the recent rolls of the dices; a property of type `[Int]` (array of integer).

There is a `join()` method of String that will concatenate your results with the separator you specify (in this case, "+"). It automatically takes care of using no separator when tehere is only one string to join ("3=3", above).

It isn't clear from your question if you only need up to the last **three** rolls, or more?

Comment: I basically want it to keep adding rolls until the user taps the clear button. I may run into more issues with content size and whatnot down the line, but I'm just trying to tackle one thing at a time haha.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it, but you could just store the values in an array and on each button press update the label and the array with the new dice roll result.

Here's some example code:

```
var results = [Int]()
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: Any) {
    var lastResult = lastDiceRollResult()
    results.append(lastResult)

    // Map goes through each item in result and lets you perform
    // an operation on it then return it. And creating a new array
    // of the returned values.
    // Then the new array is joined by "+". Where if results = [1,2,3]
    // expression would be: "1+2+3"
    var expression = results.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "+")

    // Then we append an "=" and reduce the values of results
    // into 1 one final value: the sum of results
    expression += "=" + String(results.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 })

    // expression should look like: "1+2+3=6"
    resultLabel.text = expression
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is helpful, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have some pretty good answers here.  I strongly agree with the approach of creating indexing historical values from the `IBAction` functions.  If I could add two cents, an alternative could be to have the event handlers `return dXRoll`.  The function declaration could look like this:

```
@IBAction func dXTapped(sender: UIButton) -> Int {
    let dXRoll = arc4Random_uniform(X) + 1
    rollLabel.text = "\(dXRoll)"
    return dXRoll
}
```

And then you could place `dXRoll` into a storage container (array, tuple, dictionary, etc.); an array is probably best here.  To save historical values, I would probably attempt something like this (it is more like pseudocode because I don't have Xcode in front of me to test this code):

```
let dXArrays = [4,6,8,10,12,20]; var historicalData:[Int] = []
func saveHistoricalValues() -> Array<Int> {
    for index in 0..<dXArrays.count {
        var currentDXArray = dXArrays[index]
        if currentDXArray === nil { //You can probably replace this with the ternary conditional operator, but I am very unfamiliar with that, so I did not put it in the answer.
            continue
        } else {
            historicalData.append(dXRoll[dXArrays[currentDXArray]]) //Pseudocode
        }
    }
    return historicalData
}
```

Comment: Okay great, this is definitely a lot of good information. Thanks for bearing with a newbie, I'm blown away by all of the support.

Comment: You're welcome!  No problem!  Good luck with your project!  If this helped, please remember to upvote it!